# NSImageview adding at run time does not response to mousedown event

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I created a button and a NSImageView controls at run time.  The button responded to the click event.  But the imageview does not.  Any suggestions?

```
    NSView *superview = [((MyAppAppDelegate *)[NSApp delegate]).window contentView];

    NSButton *button = [ [ NSButton alloc ] initWithFrame: NSMakeRect(300, 50, 50.0, 50.0 ) ];
    [superview addSubview:button];
    [button setTarget:self];
    [button setAction:@selector(button_Clicked:)];

    NSImageView *myImageView = [[NSImageView alloc] initWithFrame:NSMakeRect(5, 5, 240, 240)];
    NSString* filePath = @"/Volumes/MAC DAT2/pictures/TVX1/153/MP6107frame5786.jpg";
    NSImage* image1 = [[NSImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
    [myImageView setImage:image1];
    [superview addSubview:myImageView];
    [myImageView setTarget:self];
    [myImageView setAction:@selector(mouseDown:)];

}
- (IBAction)button_Clicked:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"button clicked");
}
-(void) mouseDown:(NSEvent *)event
//- (IBAction)mouseDown:(NSEvent *)event  //also have tried this one.
{
    NSLog(@"mousedown");

}
```

**Edit:** I need to use an `NSImageView`, so using an `NSButton` with an image is not a solution.

Comment: A subclass of NSObject.  However, see my comment for NSGod to clarify my question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First of all, your code has several memory issues: when you create local objects using `alloc/init`, and then hand those objects off to other objects that will retain them, you need to either `-release` or `-autorelease` the objects afterward.

```
NSView *superview = [((MyAppAppDelegate *)[NSApp delegate]).window contentView];

// memory leak averted:
NSButton *button = [[[NSButton alloc] initWithFrame:
                      NSMakeRect(300, 50, 50.0, 50.0 )] autorelease];

[superview addSubview:button];
[button setTarget:self];
[button setAction:@selector(button_Clicked:)];

// memory leak averted:
NSImageView *myImageView = [[[NSImageView alloc] initWithFrame:
                              NSMakeRect(5, 5, 240, 240)] autorelease];

NSString* filePath = @"/Volumes/MAC DAT2/pictures/TVX1/153/MP6107frame5786.jpg";

// memory leak averted:
NSImage* image1 = [[[NSImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filePath] autorelease];

[myImageView setImage:image1];
[superview addSubview:myImageView];
[myImageView setTarget:self];
[myImageView setAction:@selector(mouseDown:)];
```

`NSView`'s `-addSubview:` inserts the view into the view hierarchy, which is like an array of subviews. As a result, `-addSubview:` retains the view that you pass in, so you need to autorelease it to counteract your creation using `+alloc`. When you call `NSImageView`'s `setImage:`, it retains (or copies) the image you pass in, so you need to autorelease that also to counteract the creation using `+alloc`.

By default, `NSImageView` doesn't react to `-mouseDown:`, or `-mouseUp:` like other `NSControl` subclasses (namely `NSButton`) do. If it works visually, it might make more sense to configure an `NSButton` in a way that simply shows an image rather than using an `NSImageView`, otherwise you'd likely need to create a custom subclass of `NSImageView`.

In the `NSImageView` subclass, I would seriously contemplate whether overriding `mouseDown:` is the proper thing to do, or whether you should wait until you receive `mouseUp:` to send your action. For example, most buttons do not immediately send their action upon clicking the mouse down; rather, they wait until you let go of the mouse (`mouseUp:`), in case the user wants to change their mind.

In any case, the subclass would look like:

```
@interface MDImageView : NSImageView {

}

@end

@implementation MDImageView

- (void)mouseUp:(NSEvent *)event {
      if ([[self target] respondsToSelector:[self action]]) {
         [NSApp sendAction:[self action] to:[self target] from:self];
      }
}

@end
```

Comment: You were right on the needing subclass the NSImageView.  With that in mind, how do you implement the mouseUp event in the calling module (class) - not from MDImageView?  Basically, I need my mouse event handler methods to be resided inside the calling class.  (You can do that similar thing in C++ or C# through delegation.)  Good explanation on the memory management!