# Objective C image click action

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I have seen this in other programs and am trying to replicate it.

I have an image on one of my forms that someone can drag-and-drop an image into. I would like to allow the user to click on that image to pop up another dialog that they could instead select a "stock" image if they choose to.

I don't see an outlet I can use for the click and putting a transparent button over the top would defeat my ability to drag and drop an image on to it.

I realize I could just change the image to a button instead but I prefer to use an image if possible.

**How can I make an image clickable?**

This is OSX by the way, not IOS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quoting from [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5925571/nsimageview-adding-at-run-time-does-not-response-to-mousedown-event):

> By default, NSImageView doesn't react to -mouseDown:, or -mouseUp: like other NSControl subclasses (namely NSButton) do.

The solution is [given in an answer elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17656457/447697) - subclass NSImageView and appropriately handle the click event (as linked).

Comment: Thank you for this, I did search prior to asking my question and didn't see that one, I appreciate you linking it for me.

Answer (score 1):

Drag in the standard NSButton.

Uncheck the Bordered checkbox.

Clear the Title text.

Set the Image (and optionally, the alternate image).

Also, if you are using layout constraints to set button size to image view size, don't forget to set vertical hugging/compression resistance priorities to low values (say 1).

Comment: The asker clearly stated that "I realize I could just change the image to a button instead but I prefer to use an image if possible."